# pyfmi ModuleNotFoundError when packaging using pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pyfmi

I have a series of scripts, which include some computations with the pyfmi module. When I run the main function in my python environment (Spyder), I do not have any errors - the pyfmi computations run perfectly. But, when I package the whole thing using pyInstaller to make an executable, the pyfmi module causes issues.

I am able to run my GUI using the exe file. But whenever I click the button that calls the pyfmi library, I get an error on the console saying that 'No module named pyfmi.common.core'. I tried different import options such as `import pyfmi` , `from pyfmi import *`, `from pyfmi import fmu_util` etc., but it doesn't resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following script in order to generate your executeable:

```
import PyInstaller.__main__

PyInstaller.__main__.run(['YOUR_SCRIPT.py',
                      '--onefile',
                      '--hidden-import=pyfmi.common',
                      '--hidden-import=pyfmi.common.core',
                      '--hidden-import=pyfmi.fmi_util',
                      '--hidden-import=pyfmi.fmi_algorithm_drivers',
                      '--hidden-import=scipy._lib.messagestream',
                      '--hidden-import=assimulo.support',
                      '--hidden-import=assimulo.algebraic'
                      ])
```

This worked for me in a file which uses

```
from pyfmi import load_fmu
```

If there are further modules missing, just add them the way it is shown here.